Change the language of web application using dropdown - using views and partial views in ASP.NET Core
I have a basic web application in ASP.NET Core using MVC. The requirement is to have some kind of toggle, button, dropdown that will change the language of the page (Polish and English) - navbar, homepage and about page for now. I did it using the approach with shared resources, localization and etc., but then I was asked to do it more straightforward, by using all views and partial views in two variants: polish (i.e. Index_pl.cshtml) and english (i.e. Index.cshtml).
I did the dropdown with two buttons, duplicated all views and partial views. I tried to implement some JavaScript function and update the Controller to have this language changed on-click, but it is not working in this state.
Does anyone have any idea what can I add to this code or how can I change my implementation?
Views structure
_Layout.cshtml :
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - MelanomaWebApp</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/MelanomaWebApp.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.3/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <partial name="~/Views/Shared/_NavBar.cshtml"></partial>
    </header>

    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div class="container">
            &copy; 2024 - MelanomaWebApp - <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)

    <script>
        function changeLanguage(language) {
            currentLanguage = language;

            location.reload();
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>

_NavBar.cshtml (the same code is in _NavBar_pl.cshtml - only english words translated to polish):
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">MelanomaWebApp</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
            <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="About" asp-action="Index">About</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-dark" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                   aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <i class="bi bi-globe-americas"></i>
                    Change language (PL/EN)
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end bg-light text-center" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-item text-secondary" style="text-decoration: none;" href="#" onclick="changeLanguage('PL')">
                        <i class="pl-icon"></i>
                        Polski (PL)
                    </a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item text-secondary" style="text-decoration: none;" href="#" onclick="changeLanguage('EN')">
                        <i class="flag flag-united-kingdom"></i>
                        English (EN)
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

Index.cshtml of Home View (the same code in Index_pl.cshtml):
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div class="container text-center mt-5 mb-5 fs-3 fw-bold">
    <p>The name of the project is confidential</p>
</div>
<div class="container text-center mt-5 mb-5">
    <p>Research project No. xxxx<br />
        of some Research State<br />
        Location
    </p>
</div>
<div class="container fixed-bottom mb-2">
    <div class="row d-flex mb-5 text-center text-muted">
        <div class="col p-2">
            <p>Department of something <br />
            Some university <br />
            address <br />
            address</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col ms-auto p-2">
            <p>name of institute <br />
            address<br />
            address</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

Index.cshtml of About View(the same code in Index_pl.cshtml):
<body>
    <div class="text-center">
        <p>This is some about page content</p>
    </div>
</body>

HomeController:
using MelanomaWebApp.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace MelanomaWebApp.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
        private string CurrentLanguage { get; set; } = "EN";

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            string viewName = "Index";

            if (CurrentLanguage == "PL") 
            {
                viewName += "_pl";
            }
            return View(viewName);
        }

        public IActionResult Index_pl()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
}

In this state, when I click EN or PL button, nothing is happening, I still have default English page displayed.

How are you submitting currentLanguage from your Javascript to your Controller?


by using all views and partial views in two variants: polish (i.e.
Index_pl.cshtml) and english (i.e. Index.cshtml).

You can use JavaScript to change the language parameter in the page URL on the front end, pass it to the backend and then get the language parameter value from the query parameter to reload the page to apply the new language parameter. Here is an example you can use as a reference:
In order to effectively distinguish the language pages, I added the <h2>PL Content</h2> element to the index_pl page.
<div class="container text-center mt-5 mb-5 fs-3 fw-bold">
    <p>The name of the project is confidential</p>
</div>
<div class="container text-center mt-5 mb-5">
    <p>
        Research project No. xxxx<br />
        of some Research State<br />
        Location content
    </p>
    <h2>PL Content</h2>
</div>
<div class="container fixed-bottom mb-2">
    <div class="row d-flex mb-5 text-center text-muted">
        <div class="col p-2">
            <p>
                Department of something <br />
                Some university <br />
                address <br />
                address
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col ms-auto p-2">
            <p>
                name of institute <br />
                address<br />
                address
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

The js in _Layout:
<script>
    function changeLanguage(language) {
            
        var url = window.location.href;
        var newUrl;

        if (url.indexOf('?') > -1) {
            if (url.indexOf('language') > -1) {
                newUrl = url.replace(/(language=)[^\&]+/, '$1' + language);
            } else {
                newUrl = url + '&language=' + language;
            }
        } else {
            newUrl = url + '?language=' + language;
        }

        window.location.href = newUrl;
    }
</script>

Controller:
private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
        
public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
{
    _logger = logger;
}

public IActionResult Index()
{
    string currentLanguage = HttpContext.Request.Query["language"];

            
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentLanguage) || currentLanguage != "PL")
    {
        currentLanguage = "EN";
    }

    string viewName = "Index";
    if (currentLanguage == "PL")
    {
        viewName += "_pl";
    }

    return View(viewName);
}

Default language is English:

After selecting PL :


UPDATE:
<script>
    function changeLanguage(language) {
        var url = window.location.href;
        var newUrl;

        if (url.indexOf('?') > -1) {
            if (url.indexOf('language') > -1) {
                newUrl = url.replace(/(language=)[^\&]+/, '$1' + language);
            } else {
                newUrl = url + '&language=' + language;
            }
        } else {
            newUrl = url + '?language=' + language;
        }

       
        window.location.href = newUrl;

        
        updateChangeLanguageText();
    }

    
    function updateChangeLanguageText() {
        var currentLanguage = getQueryParameter('language');
        var changeLanguageText = document.getElementById('change-language-text');

        if (currentLanguage === 'PL') {
            changeLanguageText.innerText = 'Zmień język (PL/EN)';
        } else {
            changeLanguageText.innerText = 'Change language (PL/EN)';
        }
    }

  
    function getQueryParameter(name) {
        var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
        return urlParams.get(name);
    }

  
    window.onload = function () {
        updateChangeLanguageText();
    };

</script>

_Navbar:
<a id="change-language-text" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-dark" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
    aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
     <i class="bi bi-globe-americas"></i>
     Change language (PL/EN)
 </a>



Thank you, it changes the language of the page effectively. The only problem that I can't still resolve, is that the language of my navbar doesn't change. The pages to which it is redirecting me are in polish, but the navbar is always in english. Do you have any idea how I can fix it?

You can configure the js code to ensure that the text of the navigation bar is updated every time you change the language. I have updated the relevant code in the update section. You can use it as a reference. If you have other questions, you can post a new thread.
